# Deleting first occurrence in a doubly linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I have an assignment to do.. the task is to delete the first odd number only I wrote the code but honestly I have zero confidence about it.. if you guys can help me I would be pleased.
The function deletes the first node that has an odd value, so the function searches for the first node that has an odd value and deletes it.

```
typedef struct Node {
int data;
struct Node *next;
struct Node *previous;
 }Node;

int DeleteFirstODD(Node **front) {
int oddnum;
Node *temp = *front;


if (*front == NULL) //Checking if the list is empty
    return;


while (temp != NULL && temp->data % 2 == 0)
    temp = temp->next;

if (temp == NULL)
    return -1;

else if (temp == *front) { //if odd num founded @ the begining of the doubly 
  linked list!
    oddnum = (*front)->data;
    *front = (*front)->next;
    (*front)->previous = NULL;
    free(temp);
}
else if (temp->next == NULL) { //if odd num founded @ the end
    oddnum = temp->data;
    temp->previous->next = NULL;
    free(temp);

}
else { // if the odd somewhere in the middle
    temp->previous->next = NULL;
    temp->next->previous = NULL;
    free(temp);
}


  return oddnum;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct Node {
int data;
Node *next;
Node *previous;
 }Node;
```

is incorrect. You have to write

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
 } Node;
```

If a function has a return type that is not `void` then you may not use the return statement without an expression like in your function

```
return;
```

The function could return integer value `1` in the case when a node with an odd value was deleted or `0` otherwise.

The code within the function is incorrect. For example this loop

```
while (ptr != NULL && ptr % 2 != 0) {

    oddnum = ptr->data; 
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

does not make a sense.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int DeleteFirstODD( Node **front ) 
{
    while ( *front && ( *front )->data % 2 == 0 )
    {
        front = &( *front )->next;
    }

    int success = *front != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *current = *front;

        if ( current->next )
        {
            current->next->previous = current->previous;
        }

        *front = current->next;

        free( current );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
} Node;

int push_front( Node **head, int data )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data     = data;
        new_node->next     = *head;
        if ( *head ) ( *head )->previous = new_node;
        new_node->previous = NULL; 
    
        *head = new_node;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void display( const Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head; head= head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    puts( "null" );
}

int DeleteFirstODD( Node **front ) 
{
    while ( *front && ( *front )->data % 2 == 0 )
    {
        front = &( *front )->next;
    }

    int success = *front != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *current = *front;

        if ( current->next )
        {
            current->next->previous = current->previous;
        }

        *front = current->next;

        free( current );
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = N; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        push_front( &head, i );
    }
    
    display( head );
    
    while ( DeleteFirstODD( &head ) )
    {
        display( head );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 10 -> null
```

Comment: i have changed that part into the following one: while (temp != NULL ) {

  if(temp % 2 != 0)
  oddnum = temp->data; //storing the data from the odd node, to integer oddnum
  
  else 
   temp = temp->next;
 } //is that possible ?

Comment: @it'sM It does not matter. In this expression temp % 2 != 0 you are trying to perform the arithmetic operator % with a pointer.

Comment: Thank yyou so soooo much!!!!!! I made changes into my code to make it simple because my instructor dont give me the space to be creative with my code .. so .. the problem now is when i change node values and lets say node one value is 2 so the next node  has a value of 3 , no we need to delete the node at the middle, the problem is when i run the code its empty black command.. can you please help me with this?

Comment: @it'sM It is a bad idea to change the code in the question such a cardinal way because this will confuse readers of the question and answers. You can ask a new question with your updated code.

Comment: AHHA thank you so so so so much!!! BTW i will use your code as a reference to my assignment because my professor is such a thing  :)